# Jquery cart open many popup on adding item

Tags: jquery

Hello each time i add a product on my jquery cart the code inizilize a popup if i add 5 product befor i exit the cart i must close five popup.
How can i resolve?
I try with method destroy to close all popup but i doesn't work

```html
<script>
//
$(document).ready(function() {
    //
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
    });
    //
    $("#Carrello").click(function() {
        //
        $messageDialog = $('<div>').dialog({
            modal: true,
            open: function() {
                //
                //alert("carrello open"); 
                //
                $(this).load('carrello.php?seriale=<?php echo $seriale; ?>&var=' + nums);
                //
            },
            close: function(event, ui) {
                //
                //alert("carrello close"); 
                //
                $messageDialog.dialog("destroy");
                $messageDialog.remove();
                popUpObj.close();
                //
            },
            height: 500,
            width: 500,
            title: 'Carrello'
        });
        //
    });
    //
});
//
</script>
```

Comment: `$messageDialog` is private.  Either make an array of dialogs to close, eg: `var dialogs=[]; ... dialogs.push($messageDialog);`  or give your dialog divs a class:  `$("<div class='mydialog'>").dialog(...` `$(".mydialog").dialog("close")`